# Looking for a problem involving stochastic integration and statistics

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Does someone know a statistical problem for which stochastic integration plays a key role ? I am learning about stochastic integration and I am wondering what is it used for (I mean other than solving stochastic differential equations for finance). As I like statistics, maybe someone knows a problem that combines both subjects ?

Thank you

Comment: I can't think of anything specifically. But many models we want to estimate parameters for involve SDEs or stochastic integrals. Additionally, stochastic integration provides a means for creating martingales, which are generally useful things.

Comment: In Time Series Analysis there is the Spectral representation of a stationary stochastic process. It states, that every 0 mean stationary stochastic process can be represented by a stochastic integral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you provide a reference for this theorem ? Does it have practical applications ?

Comment: Have you looked at the so called Dickey Fuller test? It relies on the functional central limit theorem (Donsker theorem). It might be of interested to you..